# powershell remove orphan users from specific groups

Tags: permissions, groups, user

I have 5 SP Groups and it has 50+ orphan users that I need to remove from this groups (I dont want to use remove-spsuser). I just need to clean up the SharePoint groups.

Is there any powershell way to do to go through all the SharePoint groups for a site collection and remove in-active or orphan users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that worked.

```
# https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/12/find-and-delete-orphaned-alerts-in-sharepoint.html
# https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/10/remove-user-from-sharepoint-group-using-powershell.html

Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Function to Check if a User exists in AD
function CheckUserExistsInAD()
{
    Param( [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string]$UserLoginID )  
    #Search the User in AD
    $forest = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest()
    foreach ($Domain in $forest.Domains)
    {
        $context = new-object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.DirectoryContext("Domain", $Domain.Name)
        $domain = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetDomain($context)
        $root = $domain.GetDirectoryEntry()
        $search = [System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher]$root
        $search.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=User)(samAccountName=$UserLoginID)(userAccountControl=512))"
        $result = $search.FindOne()
        if($result -ne $null)
        {
            return $false
            write-host $UserLoginID
        }       
        
    }
        return $true
        write-host $UserLoginID
}
 
#Function RemoveUser-FromAllGroups($SiteURL)
#{
     #Get the Web
     #$web=Get-SPWeb $SiteURL
     $web = get-spweb "https://inside.myNOV.com/sites/OracleUpgrade"
     
     #Get the User to Remove 
     #$User  = $Web.EnsureUser($UserAccount)
 
     #Iterate through all Groups
     foreach($Group in $Web.Groups)
     {
     #write-host $group.Name
         foreach($user in $group.users)
         {
            #Exclude Built-in User Accounts , Security Groups
            if(($User.LoginName.ToLower() -ne "nt authority\authenticated users") -and($User.LoginName.ToLower() -ne "sharepoint\system") -and($User.LoginName.ToLower() -ne "nt authority\local service") -and($user.IsDomainGroup -eq $false ) )
            {
                #write-host $user
                $UserName = $user.LoginName.split("\")  #Domain\UserName
                $AccountName = $UserName[1]    #UserName         
                #write-host $AccountName
                if((CheckUserExistsInAD $AccountName) -eq $true)
                {
                    write-host $group.Name "  -  "   $user.Name " not active"
                    $Group.RemoveUser($User)
                }   
            }
         }

     }
 #}
 
 #Call the function to remove user from all groups in the site  
 #RemoveUser-FromAllGroups "https://inside.myNOV.com/sites/OracleUpgrade"
```